# Are vishnu and all his principal human(male) avataras pitambaradharis (wearers of yellow garments)?

Tags: vishnu, avatars

Vishnu Rama,Krishna.Vamana.

how about Parashurama?

Narasimha is half-human - did he wear a dress and if so what color was it?

not including Mohini.

the dhyanasloka to vishnusahasranamam says

Meghashyaamam PeetaKowsheyaVaasam
ShreeVatsaankam Koustubhotbhaasitaangam

"adorned in yellow silk"

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.rudraksha-ratna.com%2Fbuy%2Flaxmi-narasimha-puja-and-yajna&psig=AOvVaw3CkSgZeHJWg0q4SeIedjbE&ust=1650160476126000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAwQjRxqFwoTCIDbl_u8l_cCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD Narashimha is half human in the bottom so he still can wear a yellow dhoti

Comment: Still the colour of silk is yellow he is said to wear silk clothes, offcourse God being supreme will wear the heavenly silk!

Comment: Balrama - blue dhoti

Comment: balarama is said to be adisesha's incarnation @yds

Comment: Yes, but he is in few lists of dasavtaras and 24 avtaras too...